# Cauchy sequence nonconvergent in general metric space

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I know that a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is Cauchy iff it is convergent, and also convergent sequences are Cauchy in a general metric space. How does the converse fail in a general metric space? In other words, what part of the proof that Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}^d$ are convergent cannot be generalized to an arbitrary metric space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence $$\left\{\frac1n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$$ is Cauchy, but not convergent, in $(0,\infty)$ equipped with the standard metric.

Comment: Thanks, this a great example but not exactly what I was asking for. I am hoping to understand why the proof fails in the general case.

Comment: @b_pcakes Well, did you try to apply the proof to my example?

Comment: Ah, B.W. only holds in $\mathbb{R}^d$